# How to write binary to a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, binary

I am trying to get input from a file, convert the characters to binary and then output the binary to another output file.

I used Integer.toBinaryString() in order to make the conversion.

Everything is working as it should but for some reason nothing is written to the output file, but when I use System.out.println() it outputs fine.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Binary {

    FileReader fRead = null;
    FileWriter fWrite = null;
    byte[] bFile = null;
    String fileIn;

    private String binaryString(int bString) {

        String binVal = Integer.toBinaryString(bString);

        while (binVal.length() < 8) {
            binVal = "0" + binVal;
        }

        return binVal;
    }

    public void input() throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {
            fRead = new FileReader("in.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fRead);

            fileIn = reader.readLine();
            bFile = fileIn.getBytes("UTF-8");

            fWrite = new FileWriter("out.txt");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fWrite);

            for (byte b: bFile) {
                writer.write(binaryString(b));
                System.out.println(binaryString(b));
            }
            System.out.println("Done.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Binary() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        Binary b = new Binary();
        b.input();
    }

}
```

I know my code is not very good, I'm relatively new to Java so I don't know many others ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Remember to close every file that you open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Output stream instead of Writer as writer is not supposed to be used for writing binary content

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt"));
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bos.write(b); // in loop probably
```

Comment: I'm getting an error because binaryString() returns a String value and BufferedOutputStream can't write a String, what would be a workaround for this because I can't change the return type to int.

Comment: Never mind, I changed it to bos.write(b); and it wrote it to the output.txt. Thanks so much.